# свой аудиоплеер

Tags: python, python-3.x, аудио, плеер

Мне для работы требуется программный аудиоплеер, среди готовых решений подходящих к сожалению пока не нашёл, похоже придётся писать свой.

Хотелось бы узнать насколько это сложно и есть ли смысл? Посоветуйте пожалуйста в какую сторону смотреть?

Есть идейка сделать на базе web-технологий, чтобы и с сайтом интегрировать просто, или всё-таки это тупиковая идея?

Если в сторону системного программирования, то как это реализовать на python3 или на perl5, какие библиотеки лучше выбрать?

### Требуются например:

- crossfade
- 2 панели воспроизведения
- 2 панели типа файлового браузера с фильтром предположим mp3
- отображение основных id3-тегов
- и другие возможности (зависит от степени сложности реализации предыдущего)

Comment: Вариант допилить существующий не рассматривается?

Comment: @andreymal, если честно то боязно :) В чужом коде боюсь не разберусь просто, никогда не занимался подобным. Да и свой велосипед как то ближе что ли. Плюс пока пишешь - изучаешь. А что например существующее можно взять?

Comment: Можно попробовать посмотреть в сторону ffmpeg